# Why is this class and the objects of the class LOCAL in this IF statement?

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, instance

I am a beginner at this so please bear with me. It might be something really simple that I may have missed as well. Here's the code.

```
class USA { // USA CLASS
public:
    int Economy = 1000000000; 
};

void ChooseAttributes() { // THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED SOMEWHERE IN THE CODE

   if (PlayerCountryName == "USA") { // CHECK IF THE PLAYER HAS CHOSEN USA AS THEIR COUNTRY
    class Player : public USA {}; // THEN INHERIT A NEW CLASS Player FROM CLASS USA
   }

   Player myPlayer; // MAKE AN INSTANCE OF THE CLASS Player NAMED myPlayer ;
   cout << myPlayer.Economy // Print out the member ECONOMY of the object.
}
```

The problem arises when I make the instance of the class. It says that identifier Player is not defined meaning the class is not defined, right? But when I do this inside the IF statement, the instance IS created and I am able to access the members from the inherited class.  I am using VSCODE 2019, and hovering the mouse over it says that the identifier is LOCAL. How do I make a global instance of the class?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why did you put the definition of `Player` inside the `if` ? What should `Player` be when the condition is `false` ?

Comment: @kebs We can define classes in functions.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 No need to worry about that, I have made sure to not be false when it reaches that point.

Comment: Oops, correct indeed, my bad!

Comment: The way you are using this, it seems that `Country` is a property of `Player`. `USA` shouldn't be a class, but an instance.

Comment: yes there is need to worry about that, because it does not make sense to create an instance of `Player` when the class is only conditionally declared.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me that two Player objects would each have their own independent USA inheritance, rather than there being one USA object to which both Player objects refer.  Otherwise the two different inherited USA base classes in the two Player objects could have independent Economy value.  Unless each player is from an alternative reality.

Comment: @Eljay I was trying out how inheritance works in C++. It is completely unnecessary, That alternate reality thing really struck my mind though.

Comment: It is local to that scope because that's where you declared it. No mystery here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a type model in mind that's more like Python. C++ is a different language. Importantly, it's compiled.

For types, that means they are entirely created at compile time, before the first `if` statement is even run. At compile time, the relevant part is the `{ }` block. It doesn't matter whether that's `if(...) {}`, `while(...){}` or just plain `{}`, in all cases `{}` creates a block where the names inside are local to that block. Inside the block, the compiler will look outside to surrounding blocks, but the compiler will not look the other way.

This also means that in a `for(...){ }` loop, you can define a type, and that type is still defined only once. You can also define a *variable* inside a for-loop, but that variable will be initialized every time. Variable initialization happens at runtime, type definitions happen at compile time.

Comment: I see, coming from Python this is definitely different than it. I have solved the problem now, how do I close the topic?

Comment: @UtkristKarkee: There's no real "close" on StackOverflow - I've improved quite a few of my past answers over the years, when they became obsolete. The closest thing (pun intended) is marking the question as answered, which you already did.

Answer (score 0):

**It's out of scope**. As class Player is only limited within your if statement. If you want to create object of Player it should be with in scope.

For Example :

```
while(condition){
    if(condition){
        int x;
    }
    cout << x; // Error. 'x’ was not declared in this scope 
    // You can get an idea of scopes here.
}
```

Comment: The object does create within the scope but I cannot use it outside the IF statement. I need to be using it outside the function as well. Isn't it possible to make it global?

Comment: In your case, you need are inheriting person's class from USA whenever if condition is true. But i don't get your point to create it's object after if statement. You can create Person class globally but then there will be no requirement of if condition as you class inheriting from USA will be available as global object.

Comment: There are multiple conditions because their are multiple classes like US USSR FRANCE ITALY..... and I want to inherit from specific class.

Comment: @UtkristKarkee, you are confusing class instances with their definition. What you want is a class `Country` where each instance like `USA, USSR, etc.` have different values.

Comment: @Devolus Sure, that could work too but I started having more problems. Eventually I solved them. Thank you for your advice.